# Change the owner of an ntfs filesystem mounted via fstab

Tags: filesystems, executable, fstab, ntfs

I want to mount a partition on boot and need it to have read, write and execute permissions. I'm using 64-bit Arch Linux and created the following `/etc/fstab` file:

```
/dev/sda1 /run/media/luancristian/Dados ntfs    defaults    0   0
```

But it is owned by root, the output of `ls -l` is:

```
dr-x------ 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 18:51 Dados
```

I tried `sudo chown myUser Dados` but it doesn't seem to have any affect. How do I make my user the owner of this filesystem and mount it with execute permissions?

Adding the uid option to fstab, I was able to become the owner of Dados, but it still doesn't have execute permissions.

Answer (score 4):

Solved it:

became the owner of the filesystem by adding the uid option (you can find you uid on /etc/passwd) and made the filesystem executable by using ntfs-3g (had to install it):

```
/dev/sda1 /run/media/luancristian/Dados ntfs-3g     defaults,uid=1000   0   0
```